# Ordering "grün Tee"?

Tags: adjective-ending, swiss-german

Today I ordered a green tea in a restaurant, in Switzerland (Graubünden), saying "und grüne Tee". The waitress repeated my order and it sounded to me like "grün Tee". Now I'm looking at a declension table and I figure I should have said "grün**en**". What was it that I heard from the waitress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She said "[Grüntee](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gruentee)". It's one word, just like "Rotkohl" or "Blaubeere". "Grüner Tee" is very uncommon in Switzerland.

Answer (score 2):

Oftentimes the *-en* ending in DE-German (and I must say that I'm not sure whether the same is true for Switzerland or Austria) is somewhat "hidden" and when pronounced may sound like *grün'n Tee*. While this normally doesn't cause problems (*gut'n Tag*), it causes you to hear *grün* when somebody actually says *grün'n*. So you might just have misheard what she way saying.

As stated by dusky, other German speaking countries use words like *Schwarztee* or *Grüntee* instead of saying *schwarzer Tee* or *grüner Tee*, too.

Comment: I suspected this as well. But from my experience of Swiss German, -en endings are generally pronounced as -ä.